# Pressing E instantly after pressing M results in € symbol on EU keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Whenever I type "me", I actually get "m€" which is kind of annoying and I have to slow down whenever I type the "e" after the "m". Is there a way to disable this? I've never encountered this issue on Windows.
I'm using the [French](http://xahlee.info/kbd/ilayout/french_keyboard_layout_2017-04-30.svg) AZERTY layout, under Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Comment: try selecting English US as that would most probably match the EU layout more closely.

Comment: Same issue, but now it displays another symbol (epsilon) instead of euros.
PS:  I prefer AZERTY layouts